# Non duality - must it be transcendent

Tags: nonduality

I am exploring non duality. I tend to believe it's true but I'm not sure if I accept the transcendent element. Is it possible that this awareness is simply a deeper level of the mind ? That it's not part of God or a higher power. Not eternal?

Answer (score 1):

From [AN10.29](https://suttancentral.net/an10.29/en/sujato):

> Someone perceives the meditation on universal earth above, below, across, **non-dual and limitless**.
>   They perceive the meditation on universal water …
>   the meditation on universal fire …
>   the meditation on universal air …
>   the meditation on universal blue …
>   the meditation on universal yellow …
>   the meditation on universal red …
>   the meditation on universal white …
>   the meditation on universal space …
>   They perceive the meditation on universal consciousness above, below, across, non-dual and limitless.
>   These are the ten universal dimensions of meditation.
>   The best of these ten universal dimensions of meditation is when someone perceives the meditation on universal consciousness above, below, across, non-dual and limitless.
>   Some sentient beings perceive like this.
>   **But even the sentient beings who perceive like this decay and perish.**

Yes. It is not eternal.

The sutta ends with the Buddha declaring:

> But I do advocate the complete understanding of sensual pleasures, sights, and feelings. And I advocate complete extinguishment by not grasping in this very life, wishless, extinguished, and cooled.”

Regarding transcendance and theories of a self, [SN12.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.2/en/sujato) may be of interest:

> There are these four kinds of grasping.
>   Grasping at sensual pleasures, views, precepts and observances, and theories of a self.

Comment: But is there a belief that once your dead the awareness transcends you ? After death. Pre birth

Comment: Thank you. Added Buddha's answer regarding theories of a self

Answer (score 0):

It’s not transcendent, it’s immanent.  It doesn’t happen beyond or above the realm of form but rather happens within it.  There’s nothing divine about it.  It just is and goes on unnoticed.  In a sense, non dualism is a bogus and misleading concept.  Non duality is only significant because our conventional understanding is marked by dualism.  We don’t go about our day spinning philosophical missives about dualism because that’s our mundane reality.  Non dualism is equally mundane.  You don’t have non dualism, non dualism isn’t a state of mind, non dualism isn’t God.  Non dualism is simply what’s left when duality is undermined.